# converting void to string - void to object issue?

Tags: c#, object, task, void

I have the following multi threaded code, that take a list of servers and async runs the heavyoperation, the heavy operation returns the results and im trying to the populate a multiline text box with the results ( either as a batch when completed or as each task returns ), i have add some code to hopefully perform this task but the three lines below with comments on the right cause we confusion regarding void to static and void to objects :( any hints greatly received as to what i require changing....  Thanks

here is the code :-

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Progress<string> progressReporter = new Progress<string>();
    CancellationTokenSource cancelSource;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        progressReporter.ProgressChanged += progressManager_ProgressChanged;
    }

    async private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnStart.Enabled = false;
        btnCancel.Enabled = true;
        cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        textBox1.Text = await Task.Run(() => PerfromTaskAction(cancelSource.Token), cancelSource.Token); //--Cannot implicity convert type 'void' to 'string'
        await Task.Run(() => PerfromTaskAction(cancelSource.Token), cancelSource.Token);
        lblStatus.Text = "Completed.";
        btnStart.Enabled = true;
        btnCancel.Enabled = false;
    }
    static async Task PerfromTaskAction(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        object[] arrObjects = new object[] { "SERVER1", "SERVER2", "SERVER3", "SERVER4" };
        IList<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (object i in arrObjects)
        {
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) break;
            sb.Append(string.Format("{0}", tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation(i.ToString()))))); //-- Argument 2: cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation(i.ToString())));
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return sb.ToString(); //--Since 'Form1.PerfromTaskAction(CancellationToken)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression?
    }
    void progressManager_ProgressChanged(object sender, string e)
    {          
        lblStatus.Invoke((Action)(() => lblStatus.Text = e));
    }
    static string HeavyOperation(string i)
    {
        PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
        ps.AddCommand("invoke-command");
        ps.AddParameter("computername", i);
        ps.AddParameter("scriptblock", ScriptBlock.Create("get-vmreplication | select State"));
        Collection<PSObject> result = ps.Invoke();
        return(result[0].Properties["State"].Value.ToString());
    }
    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cancelSource.Cancel();
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. What is your question? 2. *"`void` to object"* makes no sense - `void` means a method doesn't return anything, you cannot convert "nothing" to an object (and it doesn't seem to be happening in your code either?) 3. What is all this code supposed to show? it's definitely not an [mcve]

Comment: if you want return string, change method to `static async Task<string>`

Comment: "converting void to string"... I'mma stop you right there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three errors, so taking them one at a time:

```
//-- Argument 2: cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'
sb.Append(string.Format("{0}", tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation(i.ToString())))));
```

The return type of `List<T>.Add` is `void`. So it can't be used as the second parameter to `string.Format`. It's not at all clear here what you *want* to do with this line of code, so I can't suggest a fix.

```
//--Since 'Form1.PerfromTaskAction(CancellationToken)' is an async method that returns 'Task', a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression
return sb.ToString();
```

This error is saying that you're in an `async Task` method (which is the async equivalent of `void`), so it can't have a return value. And yet your code is attempting to return a value.

The fix here is to change the method signature to return `Task<string>`:

```
static async Task<string> PerfromTaskAction(CancellationToken ct)
```

As for the final error:

```
//--Cannot implicity convert type 'void' to 'string'
textBox1.Text = await Task.Run(() => PerfromTaskAction(cancelSource.Token), cancelSource.Token);
```

If `PerformTaskAction` returns a `Task`, then the return type of `Task.Run(() => PerfromTaskAction(cancelSource.Token), cancelSource.Token)` is also `Task`, and this means the type of `await Task.Run(() => PerfromTaskAction(cancelSource.Token), cancelSource.Token)` is `void`. And you cannot take a `void` and assign it to `textBox1.Text`.

The fix for the last error (changing to `Task<string>`) also fixes this one. The return type of `Task.Run(() => PerfromTaskAction(cancelSource.Token), cancelSource.Token)` is now `Task<string>`, and the type of `await Task.Run(() => PerfromTaskAction(cancelSource.Token), cancelSource.Token)` is now `string`.

**Update from comment**:

Since you want to return all the strings when they all complete, this is easier to do *without* `StringBuilder`:

```
static async Task<string> PerfromTaskAction()
{
  object[] arrObjects = new object[] { "SERVER1", "SERVER2", "SERVER3", "SERVER4" };
  var tasks = arrObjects.Select(i => Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation(i.ToString())));
  var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
  return string.Join("", results);
}
```

Note that since `CancellationToken` isn't used in `HeavyOperation`, it can be removed from the `PerformTaskAction` signature.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, amending the Task<string> fixes two of them as you suggested, the outstanding one "sb.Append(string.Format("{0}", tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => HeavyOperation(i.ToString()))))); " basically the four tasks are fired off, and in the HeavyOperation im trying to return the results of the task and then appending the string builder with each returned result, then after all tasks complete returing the string builder object with the results to populate the text box on the form ( if that make some sense ? ) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**change method signature to**

```
static async Task<string> PerfromTaskAction(CancellationToken ct)

return Task(sb.ToString());
```

**and then**

```
textBox1.Text = await Task.Run(() => PerfromTaskAction(cancelSource.Token), cancelSource.Token).Result;
```